# Where can I access Sketchfab upload (and other tabs)

Tags: export, add-on

I'm currently going through the exercises in CGCookie. My latest homework is to paint over an "Axe" in order to learn how textures work.

My problem, however, is that the file that I downloaded from CGCookie (With the blank axe object)  Did not come with that tab to upload the finished and painted object to sketchfab.

I've looked up *User preferences* and even ensured that the option for Sketchfab upload was indeed clicked.

However, the tab to upload is still not visible.

Any advice in uploading my work to sketchfab?

[image: Screenshot]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgbaq.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are in *Object Mode*, not *Edit Mode*, nor *Texture Paint* mode in the menu at the bottom of the *3D View* Window Header. The tab will not show up unless you are in object mode.

Also in *User Preferences > Addons* make sure to expand the Sketchfab Addon tab and check the tab name written there. If changed the Title of the tab in the tool panel may differ.